# Make XML More Readable ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a field within a database that stores some XML data. I display this data onto a page within an application that I am creating. I currently display the data on a jquery toggle like so...

```
<a  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AllXml)
</a>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <div class="display-field">
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AllXml)</p>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that when the data is displayed on the page, it is not readable at all, as you would expect. I am wanting to make the XML data that is displayed on the page more readable. I have had a look at both Beautify and TreeView but I have no idea how this could be implemented to my solution.
Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a lot of online editors, you can embed in your page in readonly mode, in order to have a *pretty xml*, f.e. [ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pre` tag to preserve formatting strings.

```
<pre>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AllXml)</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a quick fix to my problem. I would like to implement a TreeView if possible though, but this is helpful cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get

```
 try
 {
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
     return doc.ToString();
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     return xml;
 }
```

You can use this to get an well formatted xml string that you can use in your html instead of just outputting the xml as is.
Please also not that if you are using an old version of .NET you wont have access to LINQ[ .NET < V3.5]

Comment: Thanks for your input, where in my application would this go please?

Comment: if AllXml is a string, you can use the above code and put it in a method that would return string, then set 

`model.AllXml = YourMethod(model.AllXml);`

this code would be in the controller Action.

Comment: you can also use @Html.Raw(model.Allxml) should the browser apply stying to your xml